# ffmpeg desktop capture drops audio frames but not video

Tags: ffmpeg

I run the command

```
"%~dp0bin\ffmpeg.exe" -rtbufsize 2G -f gdigrab -framerate 1/3 -draw_mouse 0 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini" -ac 1 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -movflags +faststart -c:a libopus -b:a 24k -y "output.mkv"
```

And I get the following result after 10~100 frames.

```
[dshow @ 0000000000576280] real-time buffer [Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini] [audio input] too full or near too full (72% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
frame=    7 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=  14.3kbits/
frame=    7 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=  14.3kbits/
frame=    7 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=  14.3kbits/
frame=    7 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=  14.3kbits/
[dshow @ 0000000000576280] real-time buffer [Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini] [audio input] too full or near too full (81% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
```

So, the question is: How a audio input with source stereo, 16 bit, 48KHz can make ffmpeg impossible to capture audio in an i5 CPU? Video captured fine and it is h.264.

Version of ffmpeg is:

```
ffmpeg version N-94125-gd33414d2ad Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers

built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100
libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
```

Comment: which ffmpeg version?

Comment: @RichardBarber added version

Comment: Increase the buffer: `-rtbufsize 64M`. Add it just after `-f dshow`

Comment: @Gyan Write it as solution. Finally realtime buffer is different for video and audio. And you must specify it, before specify each source (before -f option). I changed the comand to `ffmpeg -rtbufsize 2G -f gdigrab -framerate 1/3 -draw_mouse 0 -i desktop  -rtbufsize 2G -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mi.....` and it works perfectly.